# More Rows and More Columns jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am wanting a "Add Rows" and "Add Columns" button system thing. My html is:

```
<table border="2" id="the_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="value_1[]"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a href="#" rel="add_row">Add Row</a> <a href="#" rel="add_column">Add Column</a>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table_id = "#the_table";

    jQuery.fn.renderTable = function() {
        var rowCount = $(table_id + ' tr').length;
        var colCount = 0;
        $(table_id + ' tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
                colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
            } else {
                colCount++;
            }
        });

        if($(this[0]).attr("rel") == "add_row") {
            var id = $(table_id + " input:last").attr("name");
            id = id.replace(/value_(\d+)/, function(match, number) {
                return 'value_' + (parseInt(number, 10) + 1);
            });
            var x = 0;
            var result = "<tr>";
            while (x != colCount) {
                result += '<td><input name="' + id + '" /></td>';
                x = x + 1;
            }
            result += "</tr>";
            $(table_id + ' tr:last').after(result);
        }
        if($(this[0]).attr("rel") == "add_column") {

        }
    };

    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).renderTable();  

        return false;
    });
});
```

So baiscally when i click add rows i want it to add a row but increment the name of the field for php $_POST... And with add columns it must add a column and increment the names down. so my output for a 2 x 2 table would be:

```
<table border="2" id="the_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="value_1[]"/></td>
        <td><input name="value_1[]"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="value_2[]"/></td>
        <td><input name="value_2[]"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way this can be done? Thank you in advance!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to add a new `td` for each existent `tr`:

```
if ($(this[0]).attr("rel") == "add_column") {
 $(table_id + " tr").each(function() {
  var $this  = $(this),
    newInput = $("<input/>", {name:$this.find('td:last input').attr("name")}),
    newTD    = $("<td/>").append(newInput);

  $this.append(newTD);
 });
}
```

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/9LRyT/)!

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated the Fiddle and the answer with a more efficient code. Since you might use this on a large scale and everything counts towards performance :)

Comment: This is a bit off-topic and stackoverflow moderators may disagree with this comments, but usually the "new row" indicator is the CR;LF within the file! (one line in the file, one row in the database)

Comment: Thank you very much, this will surely help!